# XCode won't accept my 57x57 size icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, icons

I'm trying to archive my app with XCode. I have 4 different icons (57, 72, 114, 144).

It works fine when I drop them in but when I try to validate it after building I get the following...

[image]

If I go back and try to replace the 57px icon with a 72px icon I get this message.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Here is the values in plist, haven't done anything here manually.

[image]

Comment: could be that the png has wrong medatada in it?

Comment: what tool do you use to create the pngs?

Comment: Try something else for resizing to 57 and 72 and save them and read. I know that photoshop writes metadata. I use Pixelmator and never run in this kind of problem.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I updated my question with plist values.

Comment: Please follow the naming convention and Why have you included your splash png in icons array?????

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, he can name the pngs whatever he likes as long as he create CFBundleIcons key in his info.plist properly.

Comment: @RaymondWang Yeah I know it.but its not working for him that's why I'm suggestion him.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Here is the [apple doc for icons](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/qa/qa1686/_index.html)

In case the above link gets expired I'm including the screen shot, I know it's the content are impossible to see, [**here is the image link**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbN7R.png). Btw you can always right click on the image and copy image location and open it in new tab.

Here is how you can specify icons
[image]

[image]

Comment: @PhilipK, you can name it whatever you want, you just need to put it in info.plist.

Answer (score 3):

In theory you can name them whatever you want for iPad as long as they are in the info.plist. In order to support older version of iOS, I always name them the way apple recommand, which has already been quoted by Inder Kumar Rathore.

Take a look at [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) to see how to Add Icon files in Info.plist

@PhlipK: Your info.plist looks very different from mine, here is how mine looks like.

Take a look at the link I mentioned above and try to edit your info.plist see if that works.

[image]

Comment: Do the items correspond to different devices, or does it just match them up via image width? I wasn't originally planning on having a 50x50 icon, is that required?

Comment: you don't have to have 50x50, it is for your search results on ipad.

Comment: @PhilipK, I think your problem is your plist, try to remove the CFBundleIcons key from your info.plist and add them the way in apple's documentation, and you should be fine.